# Using #update method to create new record if one does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In `Admin::SettingsController`, I want to create a new Survey record if one does not exists, OR updates existing Survey record. What is the best *Rails* way to handle the creation and lookup? My error back is 
`No route matches [POST] "/admin/settings"`

```
edit_admin_settings_path    GET     /admin/settings/edit(.:format)  admin/settings#edit
admin_settings_path         PATCH   /admin/settings(.:format)   admin/settings#update
                            PUT     /admin/settings(.:format)   admin/settings#update
```

*routes*

```
resource  :settings,            only: [:edit, :update]
```

*controller*

```
class Admin::SettingsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :load_survey

  def edit
    @survey = Survey.find_or_initialize_by(id: params[:id]) unless @survey
  end

  def update
    @survey.update_attributes!(params_for_create_or_update)
    flash[:notice] = 'Survey updated'
    redirect_to action: :edit
  end

protected

  def load_survey
    @survey = Survey.last || Survey.new
  end

  def params_for_create_or_update
    params.require(:survey).permit(
      :name,
      :link,
      :language_id
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`find_or_create_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) method:

```
  def update
    @survey = Survey.find_or_create_by(id: params[:id])
    @survey.update_attributes!(params_for_create_or_update)
    flash[:notice] = 'Survey updated'
    redirect_to action: :edit
  end
```

This will try to find a record with that particular `id` and create one if it doesn't exist. Then you can simply update the record as you see fit.

**Edit**

you can also use [`find_or_initialize_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by) which calls `new` to instantiate the object instead of `create`

Comment: I'm using a singular resources:

So, instead of `resources` I'm using `resource :surveys, only: [:edit, :update]`. Thus, the path to edit is `admin/surveys/edit` and not `http://lvh.me:3000/admin/surveys/:id/edit`. How can I render the form if I go to `admin/surveys/edit` and there is no current survey record?

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to render `new` but then in the backend check if that record exists and update it as needed?

Comment: I updated the main post to maintain format. Using `find_or_create_by` will allow a empty record to get created to the DB on submit. Using `find_or_initialize_by` renders a POST route error @cyzanfar